# ParametricPlot and Piecewise function

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I want to create a ParametricPlot with multiple Piecewise functions in it. I have tried the following code but it doesn't work

```
ParametricPlot[Piecewise[{{Cos[x] + x/2, 1 > x > 16}, {Sin[x], 16 > x > 20}}], {x, 0, 21}, Axes -> True]
```

Basically I want my graph to show a loop but only for a certain interval, as shown in this image:

[image: loop]

I used the following command for it:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[x] + x/2, Sin[x]}, {x, 1, 16}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I'm still confused. It seems like you managed to plot what you wanted. Do you mean you want this same plot, just with `PlotRange -> {{1, 20}, All}`? Or do you want some other function plotted for `16 < x < 20` (because that is not at all clear from your initial attempt)? If so, please provide this other function.

Comment: Let me get this straight: you are plotting a trochoid, and you only want a few pieces of it, yes? Then you don't need the complication of `Piecewise[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[x] + x/2, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 21}, Axes -> True, 
               RegionFunction -> (0 < #1 < 4 || 6 < #1 < 8 &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]